# How to stop spring cloud AWS secrets manager trying to load profile based secrets

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using spring cloud AWS secrets manager support to load in configuration defined by terraform which creates the application secret defaults.

Once adding a policy statement to the services accessing the secret I run into spring not starting as it's attempting to read all kinds of secrets for profiles that do not exist in secrets manager.

How can I restrict the spring cloud secrets manager support to only read secrets I have explicitly granted access without needing to create empty secrets for every profile?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet unfortunately. We have [pull request that enables skipping loading profiles](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/pull/619) that will likely be merged in 2.3 and we are [re-thinking Secrets Manager integration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/607) for 3.0.